# warning:" initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
    for( k = 0; k < CycleCount;k++)
    {
        //make Org data
        int* Data = MakeData(DataCount[i]);
  ......
```

the function look like this one.
i think this is right. so ...

```
  int* MakeData(int DataCount)
  {
        //
   int* Data=(int*)malloc(DataCount*sizeof(int));
   int i;
   for( i=0; i<DataCount; i++)
   {
      //
      Data[i] = rand()%DataCount +1;
   }
   return Data;
 }
```

i dont know why this didn't work.

what shoud i have to do???

Comment: Which line is the warning from?

Comment: For which line do you get this warning ?

Comment: ...and what is `DataCount` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz  The symbol name DataCount is obviously used multiple times: 1. in the function `MakeData` it's an integer parameter, 2. Somewhere else where `MakeData` is called it's something else.

Comment: @harper: sure, but I implicitly meant the one in `int* Data = MakeData(DataCount[i])`, the other one being defined as a parameter in `MakeData`. I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the C compiler finds a function call without having seen a function prototype it assumes a function that returns an int.

You should tell the compiler the correct function signature with the "function prototype":

```
int* MakeData(int DataCount);
```

This should be placed in a .h file that will be included in all compilation units that call or define the function.

If you have a static function, that is visible only in the current compilation unit, you can place the prototype (incl. `static`) before all functions in that file.

Further you should never cast the return from `malloc`. It returns a `void*`. In the language C this can be converted to any other pointer type. You get the correct prototype when you `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I was about to answer :) This is the only one that is clear from the question.

Comment: @harper, your comment about my deleted answer is right, but for a slightly different reason.  `DataCount[i]` is supposed to be equivalent *(DataCount + i).  But if you wrote that it would give you an true error, and not just try to implicitly cast it to a pointer-to-int.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala Sorry, I can't read neither your deleted answer nor my comment anymore.

Comment: @Harper, sorry about that.  My answer was flat wrong, so I want it deleted.  But FYI: you said that `MakeData()` was expecting an int, not a pointer.  And my (wrong) theory was that it was, indeed getting an int, but that the dereferencing process involved an implicit int-to-pointer conversion.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala Don't worry, be happy.